# Can I add a key with right click to access the Firefox context menu?

Tags: firefox, context-menu, pentadactyl

I often hit the right click on my trackpad on accident. With Firefox open it opens the context menu.

Can I add a key, Shift, Ctrl, alt, etc., to combine with the right click to prevent this accident happening in Firefox so often? I use Firefox with Pentadactyl if that helps.

I see that there are many similar questions, but I don't see any that fit my solution or are up to date.

Comment: if you can edit the title, it might be better to change it to "Can I require a key with right click...". The current title makes it sound like you're trying to add a binding rather than restrict one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Javascript to disable the context menu except when activated with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightClick</kbd>.

```
function f(ev) { if (!ev.altKey) { ev.preventDefault(); return false; } }
document.addEventListener('contextmenu',f, false)
```

#### With Pentadactyl

Since you're running pentadactyl, you can simply add the following lines to your `.pentadactylrc`:

```
:js function f(ev) { if (!ev.altKey) { ev.preventDefault(); return false; } }
:js document.addEventListener('contextmenu',f, false)
```

#### Notes

- This will only work if the Firefox setting `dom.event.contextmenu.enabled` is set to `true`. This is the default value, so it should be fine unless you (or an extension) have changed it.

  If it's been set to `false`, you need to change it. You can do this by opening the page `about:config` in Firefox, searching for the entry and double-clicking to toggle it. Alternatively, in Pentadactyl, execute the command

  ```
  set! dom.event.contextmenu.enabled=true
  ```
- If you want to  remove the block, the can use the Javascript function

  ```
  document.removeEventListener('contextmenu',f)
  ```

  So in Pentadactyl, `:js document.removeEventListener('contextmenu',f)`

Comment: I've added the code you provided to my .pentadactylrc and confirmed that my about:config setting you mentioned was set. I still get the context menu without Alt. Is it a conflict with another add on?

Comment: No, it's my fault. I stupidly copied the wrong line. The second line is actually the one I was using to _remove_ the handler, rather than the one to add it. I've edited my answer, so it should work now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Awesome! Bonus points for the Pentadactyl explanations!